# Updating a JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i update the following JSON object dynamically using javascript or Jquery?

```
var jsonObj = [{'Id':'1','Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
               {'Id':'2','Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
               {'Id':'3','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}]
```

I would like to dynamically update the Username to 'Thomas' where the 'Id' is '3'.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It's something js understands very simply. Your question doesn't deal with JSON. It deals purely with js object manipulation. "Updating a JSON object using Javascript" is a moot expression, as it translates to "Updating a Javascript object using Javascript".

Comment: Zirak , you must be fun at parties

Answer (score 82, accepted):

A plain JavaScript solution, assuming `jsonObj` already contains JSON:

Loop over it looking for the matching Id, set the corresponding Username, and `break` from the loop after the matched item has been modified:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
  if (jsonObj[i].Id === 3) {
    jsonObj[i].Username = "Thomas";
    break;
  }
}
```

[Here it is on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cAyRs/1/)

Here's the same thing wrapped in a function:

```
function setUsername(id, newUsername) {
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    if (jsonObj[i].Id === id) {
      jsonObj[i].Username = newUsername;
      return;
    }
  }
}

// Call as
setUsername(3, "Thomas");
```

Comment: Above solution works in the fiddler. I had json string as in the question, to make it work in ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor view, I had to parse the string to json using obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj); before manipulating. Hope it helps someone. Btw I upvoted because the solution works.

Comment: This is a great solution. I took it a bit farther in my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

simply iterate over the list then check the properties of each object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; ++i) {
    if (jsonObj[i]['Id'] === '3') {
        jsonObj[i]['Username'] = 'Thomas';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var jsonObj = [{'Id':'1','Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
               {'Id':'2','Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
               {'Id':'3','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}];

    $.each(jsonObj,function(i,v){       
      if (v.Id == 3) {
        v.Username = "Thomas";
        return false;
      }
    });

alert("New Username: " + jsonObj[2].Username);

});
```

Comment: For people wondering, jQuery's `$.each()` seems [way slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808730/812102) than vanilla `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
var parsedobj = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonObj);
```

This will only be useful if you don't need the format to stay in string.
otherwise you'd have to convert this back to JSON using the JSON library.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = jsonObj.length;
while ( i --> 0 ) {
    if ( jsonObj[i].Id === 3 ) {
        jsonObj[ i ].Username = 'Thomas';
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, if the array is always ordered by the IDs:

```
jsonObj[ 2 ].Username = 'Thomas';
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON is the JavaScript *Object Notation*.   There is no such thing as a *JSON object*.  JSON is just a way of representing a JavaScript object in text.

So what you're after is a way of updating a in in-memory JavaScript object.  [qiao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702498/24874) shows how to do that simply enough.

Answer (score 2):

I took [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski)'s answer a step (or two) farther and created a more flexible function allowing any lookup field and any target field. For fun I threw splat (*) capability in there incase someone might want to do a replace all. **jQuery is NOT needed.** checkAllRows allows the option to break from the search on found for performance or the previously mentioned replace all.

```
function setVal(update) {
    /* Included to show an option if you care to use jQuery  
    var defaults = { jsonRS: null, lookupField: null, lookupKey: null,
        targetField: null, targetData: null, checkAllRows: false }; 
    //update = $.extend({}, defaults, update); */

    for (var i = 0; i < update.jsonRS.length; i++) {
        if (update.jsonRS[i][update.lookupField] === update.lookupKey || update.lookupKey === '*') {
            update.jsonRS[i][update.targetField] = update.targetData;
            if (!update.checkAllRows) { return; }
        }
    }
}


var jsonObj = [{'Id':'1','Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
           {'Id':'2','Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
           {'Id':'3','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}]
```

With your data you would use like:

```
var update = {
    jsonRS: jsonObj,
    lookupField: "Id",
    lookupKey: 2, 
    targetField: "Username",
    targetData: "Thomas", 
    checkAllRows: false
    };

setVal(update);
```

And Bob's your Uncle. :) [Works great]

Answer (score 1):

For example I am using this technique in Basket functionality.

Let us add new Item to Basket.

```
var productArray=[];


$(document).on('click','[cartBtn]',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>Added to cart');
  console.log('Item added ');
  var productJSON={"id":$(this).attr('pr_id'), "nameEn":$(this).attr('pr_name_en'), "price":$(this).attr('pr_price'), "image":$(this).attr('pr_image'), "quantity":1, "discount":0, "total":$(this).attr('pr_price')};


  if(localStorage.getObj('product')!==null){
    productArray=localStorage.getObj('product');
    productArray.push(productJSON);  
    localStorage.setObj('product', productArray);  
  }
  else{
    productArray.push(productJSON);  
    localStorage.setObj('product', productArray);  
  }


  itemCountInCart(productArray.length);

});
```

After adding some item to basket - generates json array like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "95",
        "nameEn": "New Braslet",
        "price": "8776",
        "image": "1462012394815.jpeg",
        "quantity": 1,
        "discount": 0,
        "total": "8776"
    },
    {
        "id": "96",
        "nameEn": "new braslet",
        "price": "76",
        "image": "1462012431497.jpeg",
        "quantity": 1,
        "discount": 0,
        "total": "76"
    },
    {
        "id": "97",
        "nameEn": "khjk",
        "price": "87",
        "image": "1462012483421.jpeg",
        "quantity": 1,
        "discount": 0,
        "total": "87"
    }
]
```

For Removing some item from Basket.

```
$(document).on('click','[itemRemoveBtn]',function(){

var arrayFromLocal=localStorage.getObj('product');
findAndRemove(arrayFromLocal,"id",$(this).attr('basketproductid'));
localStorage.setObj('product', arrayFromLocal);
loadBasketFromLocalStorageAndRender();
});

//This function will remove element by specified property. In my case this is ID.
function findAndRemove(array, property, value) {
  array.forEach(function(result, index) {
    if(result[property] === value) {
      //Remove from array
      console.log('Removed from index is '+index+' result is '+JSON.stringify(result));
      array.splice(index, 1);

    }    
  });
}
```

And Finally the real answer of the question "Updating a JSON object using JS". In my example updating product quantity and total price on changing the "number" element value.

```
$(document).on('keyup mouseup','input[type=number]',function(){

  var arrayFromLocal=localStorage.getObj('product');
  setQuantityAndTotalPrice(arrayFromLocal,$(this).attr('updateItemid'),$(this).val());
  localStorage.setObj('product', arrayFromLocal);
  loadBasketFromLocalStorageAndRender();
});

function setQuantityAndTotalPrice(array,id,quantity) {

  array.forEach(function(result, index) {
    if(result.id === id) {
      result.quantity=quantity;
      result.total=(quantity*result.price);
    }    
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this the more efficent way than for looping.

1-First find index of item.
2-Second edit exact element. (if not exist add)

Example :

```
let index= jsonObj.findIndex(x => x["Id"] === 3); 
if (index == -1) {
 // add
 jsonObj.push({ id:3, .... });
 } else {
  // update
   jsonObj[index]["Username"]="xoxo_gossip_girl"
 }
```

Comment: Isn't the index lacking in the "update"-part to specify which row to modify? e.g. jsonObj[index]["Username"]="xoxo_gossip_girl"

Comment: yes you are right, I edited that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var jsonObj = [{'Id':'1','Quantity':'2','Done':'0','state':'todo',
        'product_id':[315,"[LBI-W-SL-3-AG-TA004-C650-36] LAURA BONELLI-WOMEN'S-SANDAL"],
        'Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
          {'Id':'2','Quantity':'2','Done':'0','state':'todo',
          'product_id':[314,"[LBI-W-SL-3-AG-TA004-C650-36] LAURA BONELLI-WOMEN'S-SANDAL"],
          'Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
          {'Id':'3','Quantity':'2','Done':'0','state':'todo',
          'product_id':[316,"[LBI-W-SL-3-AG-TA004-C650-36] LAURA BONELLI-WOMEN'S-SANDAL"],
          'Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}];

          for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; ++i) {
            if (jsonObj[i]['product_id'][0] === 314) {


                this.onemorecartonsamenumber();


                jsonObj[i]['Done'] = ""+this.quantity_done+"";

                if(jsonObj[i]['Quantity'] === jsonObj[i]['Done']){
                  console.log('both are equal');
                  jsonObj[i]['state'] = 'packed';
                }else{
                  console.log('not equal');
                  jsonObj[i]['state'] = 'todo';
                }

                console.log('quantiy',jsonObj[i]['Quantity']);
                console.log('done',jsonObj[i]['Done']);


            }
        }

        console.log('final',jsonObj);
}

quantity_done: any = 0;

  onemorecartonsamenumber() {
    this.quantity_done += 1;
    console.log(this.quantity_done + 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

//update & push json value into json object

```
    var sales1 = [];
if (jsonObj && Object.keys(jsonObj ).length != 0) {
        jsonObj .map((value) => {
            const check = sales1.filter(x => x.order_date === String(value.order_date).substring(0, 10))
            if (check.length) {
                sales1.filter(x => x.sale_price = Number(x.sale_price) + Number(value.sale_price))
            } else {
                let data = { "sale_price": Number(value.sale_price), "order_date": String(value.order_date).substring(0, 10) }
                sales1.push(data)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily update the username dynamically to 'Thomas' where the 'Id' is '3' using the following.

```
jsonObj.find(i=>i.Id===3).Username='Thomas'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P It's a pretty straightforward answer to what OP asked