# Javascript get value from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have the following 2 files, an HTML file and a JSON file called data.txt

In the JSON:

```json
myFunction([
{
"itemid": "0",
"itemname": "air",
"currentprice": "5.0"
},
{
"itemid": "1",
"itemname": "stone",
"currentprice": "5.0"
},
{
"itemid": "2",
"itemname": "grass",
"currentprice": "5.0"
},
{
"itemid": "3",
"itemname": "dirt",
"currentprice": "5.0"
},
{
"itemid": "4",
"itemname": "cobblestone",
"currentprice": "5.0"
},
{
"itemid": "5",
"itemname": "plank",
"currentprice": "5.0"
}
]);
```

So basically, to my knowledge the only way to modify or view data from this file is with a loop like the following:

```html
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].itmid + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

<script src="data.js"></script>
```

My questions is this, is there a way to directly edit the values without a loop, possibly similar to editing arrays like itemid[number] = "customValue"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a JSON object using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702474/updating-a-json-object-using-javascript) [if the contents of data.txt are saved to a Javascript object using JSON notation]

Comment: Not entirely clear what your objectives are

Comment: It's not a duplicate, that link has a variable in the JSON, I don't. I'm using an array literal as the argument

Comment: That's JSONP, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it hard to understand what you're asking for. Are you having trouble parsing the JSON file? If so, do:

```
var str = '{"stuff":[{"itemid": "0","itemname": "air","currentprice": "5.0"},{"itemid": "1","itemname": "stone","currentprice": "5.0"},{"itemid": "2","itemname": "grass","currentprice": "5.0"},{"itemid": "3","itemname": "dirt","currentprice": "5.0"},{"itemid": "4","itemname": "cobblestone","currentprice": "5.0"},{"itemid": "5","itemname": "plank","currentprice": "5.0"}]}';
var json = JSON.parse(str); //str is the json
for (int i = 0; i < json.stuff.length; i++)
{
    //Do whatever with json.stuff[i]. i.e.:
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML += json.stuff[i].itemid; // puts each item's ID
}
```

**UPDATE**: To save the JSON to a file on *your server*, you'll need to have a server-sided script. You probably want to send an AJAX HTTP POST request to your script with the JSON string, and then the script will update your file.

Since it's on *your computer*, you can just save it using JavaScript. After you modifying the `json` variable, you can do:

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(json)], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "thefile.txt");
```

Comment: I understand, but I'm trying to keep the data in the data.txt file, and not the HTML file.

Comment: Where is data.txt located? On your computer? On a server?

Comment: Yea everything is in a folder.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo Look at my update.

Comment: why is there a var str with all the data, when the data is in data.txt

Comment: @LawrenceLelo That was for me to test it personally. For you, the `str` will be whatever you read from the file. However, you should give a name to your array. For instance, I named my array `stuff` and accessed it like `json.stuff`.

Comment: Hmm if you think it's the better idea I'll go with it. I only chose it because it seemed like a good idea, basically there is 2 ways of doing it if you look at http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_files.asp

Comment: Hey man quick question, the example here http://pastebin.com/xQFBdRRz would it be possible moving that data with the variable 'text' to its own .txt file?

Comment: @LawrenceLelo As I said, yes. You can put it in a separate text file and read the file to load the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array index to hop directly into a specific item.

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    console.log(arr[0].itemid);
    console.log(arr[0].itemname);
    console.log(arr[0].currentprice);

    console.log(arr[1].itemid);
    console.log(arr[1].itemname);
    console.log(arr[1].currentprice);
}
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. I already have a function called myFunction which is being used. How would I use your code in a different function name? Is it possible?

Comment: @LawrenceLelo You would rename "myFunction" to whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can do something like so:

```
$.grep(a, function(e){ return e.itemid == 1; });
```