# How to intercept src and Href of script and link tag in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

Does any one know if we can intercept href or src call from angular 8?

If we can't intercept from angular 8, then how can I do it from javascript ?

Comment: You can see this link for help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560062/intercept-outgoing-links-angular-4

Comment: how to achieve for for script tag. I tried use it before not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: you can see the example here, https://jsbin.com/ufexa/33/edit?html,output

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I want to add some information on API, which I don't have during coding time, when script makes GET call .

Comment: @UsmanAli, It only shows how to play with tag A. I want to interecept lets say  

``<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`` How can I intercept this call ?

Comment: See this link if it helps you, https://plnkr.co/edit/dP6wr0hB1gbXDeQs?preview