# Using routerLink with a function call

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `routerLink` with a function as follows:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="callHome(data)">Home </a>

callHome(data){
   //perform some operations
   this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
}
```

The problem here is whenever I refresh the page, without even clicking on `Home`, it automatically navigates to `/home`.

Another alternative I tried is:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home </a>
```

Here, although it works, I am not able to do the operations before navigating.

I cannot use a button and use `(click)` because I want it as a `link` as well. If I use a button, the `link` is gone.

How can I use `[routerLink]` alongwith a function call?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to place a `(click)` handler on the link element.

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" (click)="doSomeLogic()">Home</a>
```

It should perform the `(click)` handler prior to navigating with the router link.

Comment: cool, this is really a great idea. Also you can `toggle` navbar on `ngInit()`

Comment: What if doSomeLogic() function also determines in which route must [routerLink] navigate to?

Answer (score 6):

You can try like this also..
If you have manipulation in routerlink..

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="{{callHome(data)}}">Home </a>
```

It works in both methods..

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="{{otherMethod()}}" (click)="callHome(data)">Home </a>
```

I have tried it in angular 7, it is working..

Comment: This worked just fine for my case which is similar to OP

Answer (score 5):

Simply add a `(click)` event to the `<a>` tag as well. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-before-routing) in action.

Answer (score 3):

You simply must affect the string value of the route.... like this:

```
callHome(data){    
    //perform some operations    
    return "/home"; 
}
```

As stated in that stackoverflow: [Angular 5 click bind to anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177920/angular-5-click-bind-to-anchor-tag?rq=1)

You probably want to add the class `btn` to the tag to make it works like this:

```
<a class="btn" (click)="callHome(data)">Home </a>
```

Comment: If I change <a> to a button I don't get the link option.

Comment: What I mean is, I don't get an option to open in a new tab when right clicking on the button

Comment: If you want to open it always in a new tab, you could do: this.window.open("/home"); in your click.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I don't want to always open in new tab, just want it the option to be present

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the asked question. In my opinion, you should never blindly rely on a priority or order of execution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular with Ionic, and I had to set the routerLink to null and use the (click) event.

```
<ion-item routerLink="{{null}}" (click)="logOut()" lines="none" detail="false">
  <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out-outline" class="log-out-icon"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Log Out</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

**This ensures you get NO ionic routing animations AND full keyboard accessibility.**